# Just purchased a home and was wondering what types of trees the were

Tags: identification, trees

Small tree had green leaves but they turned purple in early summer and now they also purple sweet smelling berries[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [purple](https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/prunus-cerasifera-thundercloud) leaf cherry, or plum.

Answer (score 0):

I think b.nota is right...Myoblan Plum to be specific. [image: Myoblan Plum]

Yours might be Prunus ceracifera 'Nigra'.  [image: Prunus ceracifera 'Nigra']